# JPQL select previous and next row

Tags: sql, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Assume I have a table with a dates which are

1. not ordered
2. not all exist(2019/11/01, 2019/11/02, 2019/11/05)

I need for specific date select previous or same and next. Assume I have a table

```
|-------------|
|    Date     |
|-------------|
| 2019/11/01  |
|-------------|
| 2019/11/02  |
|-------------|
| 2019/11/03  |
|-------------|
| 2019/11/05  |
|-------------|
```

if I try to select result for date `2019/11/03`, then result must be `2019/11/03`(same) & `2019/11/05`(next)

if I try to select result for date `2019/11/04`, then result must be `2019/11/03`(previous) & `2019/11/05`(next)

I know how to do this with two separate queries, but I hope that there is a way to do it in a single one?

Comment: Can you share the two separated queries? This is help us to understand better your problem and what did you try until now.

Comment: subselects are in JPQL forbiden in SELECT and FROM parts, through they can be used in WHERE clausule part. Have you tried something like this: `SELECT d FROM dates d WHERE d.id = (select max(dStart.id) from dates dStart where dStart.date <= :inputDate) or (select min(dEnd.id) from dates dEnd where dEnd.date > :inputDate)` This assumes that id column is monotonic in comparison to its date part (i.e. sorting by id or by date does sort rows in same order).